# Configuring Approval page layout for user-selectable rejection reason

Tags: approval-process

can we add a pick-list field to the Approval pagelayout ??

My requirement is i want Approvers to enter Reason for rejecting a record.

I have a picklist field on my object with the rejection reasons , i want this field to be placed on the approval page layout so that Approvers select reason from this pick-list.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can edit the approval page layout once you have created your approval process. When viewing the approval process detail, click on the Edit button, and then the Approval Page Layout option from the menu:

[image: Menu for the edit button]

That will take you through to a screen with a multi-select picklist of the fields on the page, and you should be able to choose your picklist field there:

[image: Approval process detail page layout field selection]

Comment: We can add fields only to display on Approval pagelayout,is there any way we can add the picklist field and select the value from the field before accept or reject.

Answer (score -2):

I could add the required field Rejection Reason, but I am unable to get the pick-list value.
[image]

Comment: Actually, I have used the method above. to add an extra field on the approval layout page. But the problem is it's not displaying the pick-list value for the custom field I added to the Custom object.

Comment: @DominicSeb check if the question I've linked to as a dupe helps you