# Can we customize Reassign Approval Request

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am having a requirement, where we have to write a Custom visualforce Page which will do the same thing as Standard "Reassign Approval Request" page. Below is the screenshot of Standard Reaasign page.

[image] 
    I am writing this functionality on opportunity, so I can easily get the Related to and Craeted by fields, But How can I get the fields like "Approver", "Assigned Approver" and "Comment field".

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to check the tables used in approval processes: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_process.htm

For example query the [`ProcessInstanceStep`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_processinstancestep.htm) (best would be to just start sniffing around in your system, perform a reassignment and figure out what changes in these tables). "Step" doesn't support updates but looks like "WorkItem" table does so fingers crossed?

Another important thing could be the [Apex class for Approvals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_approval.htm), here's [sample usage](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_process_example.htm).

---

It's been a while since I played with Apex solutions around approvals... Around 1 year ago I've posted an answer for customized approval page, maybe you will be able to salvage something from the code: [Custom fields not useable in Approve/Reject Approval Request](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12481/custom-fields-not-useable-in-approve-reject-approval-request)