# Add radio button or check box in approval layout page

Tags: custom-field, page-layout

is it possible if I want to put a radio button or check box in this page? I want to ask user(manager) either it is a final approval or not. If it is possible, may I know how?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont think currently it is possible to add input fields to the Approve/Reject Approval Request Page.
There is already an idea which exists for the same.

You can go ahead an Upvote for it so that it can be picked by the Salesforce team for upcoming releases.Please check the merged ideas too.

Please find the link below :

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kP95AAE
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpZzAAK

Also you can refer the below link if you are looking for some custom solution or a workaround for this:
[Custom fields not useable in Approve/Reject Approval Request](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12481/custom-fields-not-useable-in-approve-reject-approval-request)